# hint.css IE8 transparent background bug

Tags: internet-explorer-8, transparent

IE8 transparent background of hint bug(tooltip show under content)
modification only: white-space: pre-wrap; (because of multilines)

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9686181/5003427/d5514c36-6a15-11e4-959d-7cff3c753c39.png

Bug is also in developer examples http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/ (with IE8)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a background color transparent in ie8.

What you can do is set a background image and make that transparent.

[transparent background issue IE8, IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933713/transparent-background-issue-ie8-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

Try Internet Explorer - Alpha Filter !!

Here is the syntax:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(parameters);
```

For IE-8

```
 filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=<Opacity Value>)";
```

Reference:[Alpha Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)